# How long is session stored in express-session on server?

Tags: node.js, express, session, session-cookies, express-session

I have used ExpressJS with express-session for Session Management. According to its NPM page, we can add a maxAge and cookies.expires. But, both of these manage the expiration date of the cookies. But what about the server side? For how long does the session store keep the sessions? What if we don't set the maxAge and cookies.expires and the user closes the browser abruptly? Will the session data on server side be stored permanently without removal?

Comment: If you don't set maxAge then it will stay on the server till the app is running (restarting will remove the session stored on the server)

Answer (score 0):

No it won't. The session data is stored in the memory(RAM) if you haven't specified a separate store(e.g. redis,mongodb, etc.)

When you shut down the server all the info will be removed

Comment: The question is regarding a separate session store. What happens if we are using a separate session store like mongo or redis, and the user shutsdown the browser without logging out?

Comment: Basically the session data gets stored in the database that you selected. Typically when configuring `express-session` you get a parameter with the name of `store`. Here's the documentation for using it https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores

Comment: I know how to use the session stores. what I am asking is how long is session data stored in the store for

Comment: It will persist forever until your server is running. There's nothing indicated about the default expiry time in the documentation. In your question you have asked a different thing, that's why I wasn't able to provide you with an answer for the first time

Comment: the answer is not related to the question

Answer (score 0):

The stuff inside the session will live until the cookie expires